# Run jquery code every time partial view is rendered with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I'm using Ajax.Actionlink's to render partialview in MVC. I'm also using Modernizr datepicker so firefox could be as nice as Chrome with input type=date.

When I click my first Ajax actionlink the datepicker works fine. But when I click on it again it doesn't work at all.

If i reload the page (F5) it works again, first time, not second and later.

How do I fix it so the jQuery code runs every time, even if I switch to another partial view?

My JS:

```
<script>
    $.noConflict();  
    if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
        $('input[type=date]').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    }
</script>
```

EDIT: I've tried wrapping the JS in $(function () {...}); and the code is inside the partial view. Also tried using the OnSuccess option but the result is the same. It only runs the first time and after that I need to reload the page

EDIT 2:

My Ajax actionlinks:

```
<div id="createCalcMenu">
@Ajax.ActionLink("Annuity", "Annuity", "Calculation", new AjaxOptions
        {
             UpdateTargetId = "calcDiv",
             InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
             HttpMethod = "POST"
        })
                    <br />              
@Ajax.ActionLink("Amortization", "Amortization", "Calculation", new AjaxOptions
        {
             UpdateTargetId = "calcDiv",
             InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
             HttpMethod = "POST"
        })
</div>
    <div id="calcDiv"></div>
```

EDIT 3:

My partialview:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ShowDetailAnnuity", "Calculation", new AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "CalcDetail",
    LoadingElementId = "Loader"
}))
{
<input type="date" id="StartDate" name="startdate" title="Please enter start date (YYYY-mm-dd)" class="startDateTextbox" required />

//Rest of the form here...

<input type="submit" id="calcBtn" class="calcBtn" name="SubmitValue" value="Calculate" title="Calculate your calculation" />
}


<script>
$(function () {
    $.noConflict();
    if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
        $('input[type=date]').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: put this script inside partial view or add this script in the ``OnSuccess`` of ``Ajax.ActionLink``

Comment: The script is inside the partial view

Comment: you are using jQuery so wouldn't this be in `$(function(){...});` doc ready block.

Comment: @Jai same result as the code I have (tried it)

Comment: I also tried adding OnSuccess = "alert('blabla')" to the actionlinks, but it (just as the jquery code) only runs the first time. Then I need to reload the page for it to show again

Comment: put it OnSucess of ajax action link

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Tried that. Same result (read edit)

Comment: put only this line in OnSuccess ``$('input[type=date]').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });``

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Didn't work either. Not even the first time page is loaded

Comment: Can you share your partial view code? the one which have the date input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be with jQuery

I replicated your code and just did a small change in the script of the partial view. 
When I first ran the code, it gave me an error saying $ is not defined (though I have included the jQuery library to the main layout).
I manually called jQuery in the partial layout and it worked. I hope it helps you.

Following is the change that I have done in Annuity partial view code:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
          $.noConflict();
          if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
              $('input[type=date]').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
          }
    });
</script>
```

No matter how many times I click on the link the datepicker always comes for me. Also make sure you have your references to the JS files jquery and mordernizr only once (in the main layout)

Comment: Tried it with the same result. Can't really understand why. Maybe some trouble with conflicts or something

Comment: How are you calling your scripts in the theme?

I mean to ask is that is mordernizr called after jQuery?

Comment: Yes, modernizr is called after

Comment: I think I might know why you are getting this.

Have you included the jQuery js file in your partial view as well? If you have then you should remove the references in the Partial view (both jquery and mordernizr) and have them called only once in the main layout and then use the script that I have mentioned.

Comment: I've only linked jquery and modernizr in my main layout view

Comment: hmmmmm.....
I tried adding the jquery and mordernizr in the partial view and it did the same as it was doing with you...

Can you test in the browser console as to what calls are being made by ajax?

Comment: It says (the second time): TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: Solved it. Used jQuery.noConflict(). Thanks for all help @progrAmmar

Comment: Update your answer and you will get the marked answer